# Write a java program that prints a pyramid of numbers using only a while loop

Tags: java, nested-loops

It needs to look like this:

[image: It needs to look like this]

I have a for loop code that works but I can't turn it into a correct while loop one.

Here is the for loop code:

```java
public class NumPyramid {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int rows = 9;

        for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= (rows - i) * 2; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            
            for (int k = i; k >= 1; k--) {
                System.out.print(" " + k); //create left half            
            }
            for (int l = 2; l <= i; l++) {
                System.out.print(" " + l); //create right half
            }
            
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I have a `for` loop code that works"* then what's the matter? That's the correct way to do something a certain number of times. `while` loops are for other kinds of stuff.

Comment: @Federico It's probably homework. "Recognize that homework is likely to include artificial constraints, and honor those constraints" (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon you're probably right (I missed "using only a while loop" in the title). Let's prefix my previous comment with "for your future endeavors", then :)

Answer (score 4):

In general, this is how you convert a `for` loop to a while loop:

```
for (initial; condition; iterate) {
    statement;
}
```

becomes

```
initial;
while (condition) {
    statement;
    iterate;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did and it works!

```
  int rows = 9, i = 1;

   while (i <= rows)
    {
        int j = 1;
        while (j<=(rows-i)*2)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
            j++;
        }
        int k = i;
        while (k >= 1)
        {
            System.out.print(" "+k);
            k--;
        }
        int l = 2;
        while (l<=i)
        {
            System.out.print(" "+l);
            l++;
        }
        System.out.println();
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `StringBuilder` to hold the entire string you need to print and fill it with spaces.

For the initial step you set `'1'` into the middle and print the contents of the string.
After that you "move" to the left and right, set the next `i` and repeat printing until all rows are done.

**Update**
Added `space` parameter to control the distance between digits in the pyramid.

```java
int n = 9;
int i = 1;
int space = 2; // distance between two adjacent digits
int width = 2 * space * (n - 2) + 1; // 0 not included

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (i++ <= width) {
    sb.append(' ');  // prepare StringBuilder with whitespaces
}

i = 0;
int left = width / 2;
int right = width / 2;
while (i++ < n - 1) { // print 1..8
    sb.setCharAt(left, (char)(i + '0'));
    sb.setCharAt(right, (char)(i + '0'));
    System.out.println(sb);
    left -= space;
    right += space;
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about this way. Thank you

Comment: Yes, in this approach multiple Strings are not created.  I updated with a parameter to control distance between digits.